# focusin event using on not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, focusin

I am attempting to perform some action on the `foucsin` of the textbox.  However, for some reason the event never fires.

```
$(".ddlAddListinTo li").click(function () {
    var urlstring = "../ActionTypes";
    $.post(urlstring, function (data) {
        $(window.open(urlstring, 'Contacts', 'width=750, height=400')).load(function (e) {

      //  Here "this" will be the pop up window. 
             $(this.document).find('#txtAutocompleteContact').on({
                   'focusin': function (event) {
                   alert('You are inside the Contact text box of the Contacts Popup');
                         }
                    });
               });
         });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing it that way, you generally have to find the body or use `contents()` to access the contents, as in

```
$(this.document).contents().find('#txtAutocompleteContact')
```

but in this case using a little plain javascript seems more appropriate :

```
$(".ddlAddListinTo li").on('click', function () {
    var urlstring = "../ActionTypes";
    $.post(urlstring, function (data) {
        var wind = window.open(urlstring, 'Contacts', 'width=750, height=400');

        wind.onload = function() {
             var elem = this.document.getElementById('txtAutocompleteContact');

              $(elem).on('focus', function() {
                  alert('You are inside the Contact text box of the Contacts Popup');
              });
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried both but no luck.

Comment: Then you'll have to do some debugging, console log this.document and see what you get etc.

Comment: I attempted to add an input element into the form field of the popup and it did work.                                                       var $formCopy = '<input id="SelectedMlsnums" name="Selectednums" type="hidden" value="' + Selectednums + '">'                                                        
                                                                                           $(this.document).find("#divfrmInfo").html($formCopy);

Comment: but   $(this.document).contents().find('#txtAutocompleteContact').on({  });  is not working.